# How to detect browser when using CloudFront

Tags: joomla, user-agent, amazon-cloudfront

We've got a joomla website which is using UserAgent to detect whether the user is using a mobile device and assigns a template accordingly.

We're moving to AWS and want to use CloudFront.  Unfortunately CloudFront changes the UserAgent to 'Amazon CloudFront' preventing us from detecting the device of the end-user

Has anyone else found a solution to this?  Searching the AWS support forums has a yielded not answers, we can't be the only ones to have this issue.

Comment: This may be a bad idea.  You won't be able to use cache if you use server-side detection.

Comment: This is becoming our conclusion. Well mine, others are a little stubborn haha.  I think we should only use it for static resources.  And later down the line maybe look into a responsive site design, which I think is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: I agree, go responsive, it's much easier

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/user-agent.html), you can detect whether the user is on a mobile or desktop using the following:

```
var match = /\bSilk\/(.*\bMobile Safari\b)?/.exec(navigator.userAgent);
if (match) {
    alert("Detected Silk in mode "+(match[1] ? "Mobile" : "Default (desktop)"));
}
```

After using the code above, you can then write `if else` statements to display your desired template.

I am a Joomla user, however have not ever used AWS with it so I could be entirely wrong about this.

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately Silk only works with Kindle Fire which is a shame.  EDIT: it's actually amazon's attempt at a browser by the looks of things